# How to copy data specific amount of times in VBA excel?

Tags: vba, excel

Let's say I have data in cell `A1` called `"Max"`, I want to copy the value of `A1` 120 times. And then I have another data in cell `A121` called `"Ben"`, I want to copy it 400 times. And so on...
I'm not going to always copy 120 times or 400 times only. Sometimes it's 100 times, sometimes it's 500 times, or 1000 times. And I must do that to many data.
I already use

```
Range("A1").Copy Range("A120")
Range("A121").Copy Range("A279")
```

But I think it's not so effective since I have to count the difference butween the number of times I want to copy the data and the last number of row.
If you don't get it clearly, take a look from my case. I already copy `"Max"`  120 times, and it ends in cell `A120`. When I try to continue copy `"Ben"` 400 times, I must know which cell should it ended, which is in this case `A279`. I got `A279` by subtracting `400-121(1 cell after the last cell of "Max")`. I can't do this if there's a lot more value that I have to copy. It's not effective.

**So, The question is**. Is there any way to copy the value of a cell by only providing how much times you want to copy?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, but would this work:  `Range("A1").Copy Range("A1:A120")` and `Range("A121").Copy Range("A121:A400")` (or `Range("A121").Copy Range("A121:A279")` depending on what you want)?

Comment: you may wan to link "after" and "before" scenarios of your sheet and let us understand your aim. for instance how is the code supposed to know how many times it has to paste down a value?

Answer (score 0):

the strict answer to your question

> Is there any way to copy the value of a cell by only providing how
>   much times you want to copy?

is:

```
cell.Resize(nTimes).Value = cell.Value
```

where:

- `cell`, is a variable holding a valid reference to a range consisting of one cell only
- `nTimes`, is the number of times you want to replicate the `cell` value starting from the `cell` itself and going down the (`nTimes`-1) cells below it